# Complex mongo array query

Tags: mongodb

with given collection "foo", we have field "bar" that looks like this:

```
"bar": [{uid:1, mid: 10}, {uid:1, mid: 12}, {uid:2, mid: 14}, {uid:2, mid: 15}, {uid:2, mid: 18}]
```

How can I make a query to fetch all "foos" on the field "bar" that satisfies following condition:  **"uid" = 2 and "mid" in [14, 18]**

Comment: you can unwind it. Then, it's easier to make such kind of query. You want to do this query for all collections ?

Comment: Isn't $unwind used only for aggregation framework? No, I just want to query one collection.

Comment: you are right, it is used in aggregation. I was thinking in complex way while it can be done so easily. My bad...

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to interpret your condition

> all "foos" on the field "bar" that satisfies following condition: "uid" = 2 and "mid" in [14, 18]

Do you mean "find all documents in the `foo` collection such that there is an element `e` of the `bar` array satisfying `e.uid = 2` and `e.mid` is an element of [14, 18]"? If so, the MongoDB query, written in the mongo shell, is

```
db.foo.find({ "bar" : { "$elemMatch" : { "uid" : 2, "mid" : { "$in" : [14, 18] } } } })
```

Do you mean "find all documents in the `foo` collection such that there is a `bar.uid` value of 2 and `bar.mid` value in [14, 18]"? If so, the MongoDB query, written in the mongo shell, is

```
db.foo.find({ "bar.uid" : 2, "bar.mid" : { "$in" : [14, 18] } })
```

The following example demonstrates the differences between these queries:

```
> db.foo.drop()
> db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 0, "bar" : [{ "uid" : 2, "mid" : 14 }] })
> db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 1, "bar" : [{ "uid" : 2, "mid" : 99 }, { "uid" : 3, "mid" : 18 }] })

// first version
> db.foo.find({ "bar" : { "$elemMatch" : { "uid" : 2, "mid" : { "$in" : [14, 18] } } } })
{ "_id" : 0, "bar" : [{ "uid" : 2, "mid" : 14 }] }

// second version
> db.foo.find({ "bar.uid" : 2, "bar.mid" : { "$in" : [14, 18] } })
{ "_id" : 0, "bar" : [{ "uid" : 2, "mid" : 14 }] }
{ "_id" : 1, "bar" : [{ "uid" : 2, "mid" : 99 }, { "uid" : 3, "mid" : 18 }] }
```

Comment: Hi! Close enough. However, "bar.mid" MUST have all members from given expression "$in": [14,18]. I tried with "$all" operator, but nothing happens...